# MySQL with FullCalendar is writting to SQL database but not reading/updating properly

Tags: python, sql, flask, fullcalendar, mysql-python

I am trying to build a Web application that allows for a scheduler to interact with an SQL database.

It is able to store the inputted event to the server but does not display to the application despite being present in the database.

This is my code for writing and updating the events of which is returning an error after it has left the 'POST' function.

```
@app.route("/insert",methods=["POST","GET"])
def insert():
    print("before")
    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    print("after")
    if request.method == 'POST':
        title = request.form['title'] 
        start = request.form['start']
        end = request.form['end']
        print(title)
        print(start)
        cur.execute("INSERT INTO events (title,start,end) VALUES (%s,%s,%s)",[title,start,end])
        print ('pre committ')
        mysql.connection.commit()
        print('post commit')
        cur.close()
        msg = 'success'
        print('done')
```

This is to update, when I step through the code, this does not run.

```
@app.route("/update",methods=["POST","GET"])
def update():
    print("in commit")
    cursor = mysql.connection.cursor()
    cur = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        title = request.form['title']
        start = request.form['start']
        end = request.form['end']
        id = request.form['id']

        print(title)
        print(start)
        cur.execute("UPDATE events SET title = %s, start = %s, end = %s WHERE id = %s ", [title, start, end, id])
        mysql.connection.commit()
        cur.close()
        msg = 'success'
    return jsonify(msg)
```

This is what comes out in the terminal:

```
before
after
Test event
2021-07-14 07:30:00
pre committ
post commit
done
[2021-07-14 15:06:01,333] ERROR in app: Exception on /insert [POST]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\samue\source\repos\Oper Fast WebApp-V1\Webenv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "C:\Users\samue\source\repos\Oper Fast WebApp-V1\Webenv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1953, in full_dispatch_request
    return self.finalize_request(rv)
  File "C:\Users\samue\source\repos\Oper Fast WebApp-V1\Webenv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1968, in finalize_request
    response = self.make_response(rv)
  File "C:\Users\samue\source\repos\Oper Fast WebApp-V1\Webenv\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2097, in make_response
    raise TypeError(
TypeError: The view function did not return a valid response. The function either returned None or ended without a return statement.
127.0.0.1 - - [14/Jul/2021 15:06:01] "←[35m←[1mPOST /insert HTTP/1.1←[0m" 500 -
Error on request:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\samue\source\repos\Oper Fast WebApp-V1\Webenv\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 323, in run_wsgi
    execute(self.server.app)
  File "C:\Users\samue\source\repos\Oper Fast WebApp-V1\Webenv\Lib\site-packages\werkzeug\serving.py", line 312, in execute
    application_iter = app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\samue\source\repos\Oper Fast WebApp-V1\Webenv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2464, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "C:\Users\samue\source\repos\Oper Fast WebApp-V1\Webenv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2458, in wsgi_app
    ctx.auto_pop(error)
  File "C:\Users\samue\source\repos\Oper Fast WebApp-V1\Webenv\Lib\site-packages\flask\ctx.py", line 452, in auto_pop
    self.pop(exc)
  File "C:\Users\samue\source\repos\Oper Fast WebApp-V1\Webenv\Lib\site-packages\flask\ctx.py", line 438, in pop
    app_ctx.pop(exc)
  File "C:\Users\samue\source\repos\Oper Fast WebApp-V1\Webenv\Lib\site-packages\flask\ctx.py", line 238, in pop
    self.app.do_teardown_appcontext(exc)
  File "C:\Users\samue\source\repos\Oper Fast WebApp-V1\Webenv\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2321, in do_teardown_appcontext
    func(exc)
  File "C:\Users\samue\source\repos\Oper Fast WebApp-V1\Webenv\Lib\site-packages\flask_mysqldb\__init__.py", line 100, in teardown
    ctx.mysql_db.close()
MySQLdb._exceptions.OperationalError: (2006, '')
```

Comment: Any reason you are opening two cursors?

Comment: That is what the tutorial I followed said, I am new to SQL sorry. They appear to be opening different things.